Error when using cms.api.create_page "UserWarning: No user has been supplied when creating a new PageContent object."
When I use the Django CMS API "create_page" function I get the following error:
UserWarning: No user has been supplied when creating a new PageContent object. No version could be created. Make sure that the creating code also creates a Version objects or use PageContent.objects.with_user(user).create(...)
  page_content = PageContent.objects.with_user(user).create(


When the "create_page" function is run it creates a page and then runs the "create_page_content" function which throws an error at the following line of code:
user = getattr(_thread_locals, "user", "unknown user")
page_content = PageContent.objects.with_user(user).create(
    language=language,
    title=title,
    menu_title=menu_title,
    page_title=page_title,
    redirect=redirect,
    meta_description=meta_description,
    page=page,
    created_by=created_by,
    changed_by=created_by,
    soft_root=soft_root,
    in_navigation=in_navigation,
    template=template,
    limit_visibility_in_menu=limit_visibility_in_menu,
    xframe_options=xframe_options,
)

This is part of Django CMS' inbuilt API so I can't really change it.  I could copy the "create_page" and "create_page_content" functions and use the edited copies but that seems like a fairly brute force solution and I'm probably just missing something.
My relevant code:
from cms.api import create_page
from cms.constants import TEMPLATE_INHERITANCE_MAGIC

new_page = create_page(title='Example', template=TEMPLATE_INHERITANCE_MAGIC, language='en')

django version: 5.0.1
django-cms version: 4.1.0
python version: 3.12.2

show your PageContent model

Solved: I needed to add a "User" object as the "created_by" parameter e.g:
from cms.api import create_page
from cms.constants import TEMPLATE_INHERITANCE_MAGIC
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

new_page = create_page(title='Example', template=TEMPLATE_INHERITANCE_MAGIC, language='en', created_by=User.objects.get(username='user'))

By default the "created_by" parameter is set to the string 'python-api' which doesn't work. 
The comments in the api refer to the check for a User as an "ugly permissions hack" so I assume this is something that the devs know is a problem.

Indeed, since Django CMS 4, the created by argument is obligatory.
